# flutter app (android) builds app bundle, but there are some warnings

Tags: flutter, android-app-bundle

flutter buid appbundle suceeds, but there are some warnings:

> Note: /Users/mateus/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-9.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/analytics/FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Note: /Users/mateus/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-9.1.0/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/analytics/FlutterFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

> Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

How can I correct them? I tried to recompile as suggested but wasn't able

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those errors are from the firebase analytics plugin and have nothing to do with your code.

Here are the issues you can follow, when there's a fix you'll hear about it there:
[Issue one](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/8073), [Issue two](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4115) and [Issue three](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1389).